# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError even though libraries and classes have method

Tags: java, java-native-interface, unsatisfiedlinkerror

I am using Python and Py4J to test JNI code. But when I call the JNI code I get the following error:

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o37.createInstance.
: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.mgr_api_JNI.createInstance(Lcom/mgr_api_types$EDisplayType;Ljava/lang/String;Lcom/mgr_api_types$ECommType;Ljava/lang/String;)V
    at com.mgr_api_JNI.createInstance(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

I have looked at these links [link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15312362/java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror-native-method-not-found), [link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28603269/unsatisfiedlinkerror-native-method-not-found-but-correct-naming), [link 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24566127/jni-java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror-native-method-not-found), [link 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33257708/unsatisfiedlinkerror-native-method-not-found-with-so-file-correctly-put-in-ecl), [link 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23347743/java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror-native-method-issue), and [link 6](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/738b7897-cd38-4f24-9f05-48dd69116837/entry/debugging_java_lang_unsatisfiedlinkerror9?lang=en), plus others, but none of them solve my problem.

### Code

**mgr_api_JNI.java:**

```
package com;
import com.mgr_api_types.*;

public class mgr_api_JNI
{
    static
    {
        try
        {
            System.loadLibrary("Mngr"); // Use "-Djava.library.path=[path to library]" option to load this library
        }
        catch (UnsatisfiedLinkError e)
        {
            System.err.println("Native code library 'Mngr' failed to load.\n" + e);
        }
    }

    public native void createInstance(com.mgr_api_types.EDisplayType displayType,
                                      String displaySerialNumber,
                                      com.mgr_api_types.ECommType commType,
                                      String portName);
}
```

**testsJNI.java:**

```
import com.*;
import py4j.GatewayServer;

public class testsJNI
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        testsJNI testApp = new testsJNI();

        // Py4J server
        GatewayServer server = new GatewayServer(testApp);
        server.turnLoggingOff();
        server.start();
    }
}
```

**com_mgr_api_JNI.h** (created by using javac -h on mgr_api_JNI.java):

```
/* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is machine generated */
#include <jni.h>
/* Header for class com_mgr_api_JNI */

#ifndef _Included_com_mgr_api_JNI
#define _Included_com_mgr_api_JNI
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
/*
 * Class:     com_mgr_api_JNI
 * Method:    createInstance
 * Signature: (Lcom/mgr_api_types/EDisplayType;Ljava/lang/String;Lcom/mgr_api_types/ECommType;Ljava/lang/String;)V
 */
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_mgr_1api_1JNI_createInstance
(JNIEnv *, jobject, jobject, jstring, jobject, jstring);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

**com_mgr_api_JNI.cpp:**

```
#include "com_mgr_api_JNI.h"
static manager::CManagerApi* manager = NULL;

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_mgr_1api_1JNI_createInstance(
                            JNIEnv *env,
                            jobject thisObj, 
                            jobject displayType,
                            jstring displaySerialNumber,
                            jobject commType,
                            jstring portName)
{
  manager::EDisplayType dType = convertObjectToDisplayType(env, displayType);
  const char* serialNumber = env->GetStringUTFChars(displaySerialNumber, 0);
  manager::ECommType comm = convertObjectToCommType(env, commType);
  const char* port = env->GetStringUTFChars(portName, 0);

  char buf[100];
  sprintf(buf,"%s",port);
  std::string portStr = buf;

  sprintf(buf,"%s",serialNumber);
  std::string serialNumStr = buf;

  if (manager == NULL)
  {
    manager = manager::CManagerApi::get();
    manager->initialize(dType, serialNumStr, comm, portStr);
  }

  // Release memory
  env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(displaySerialNumber, serialNumber);
  env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(portName, port);
}
```

Command line execution of Java code:

```
java -cp /mnt/c/Workspace/library/java/:.:/home/fred/.local/share/py4j/py4j0.10.7.jar -Djava.library.path=/mnt/c/Workspace/build/library/ testsJNI
```

Doing a `-XshowSettings:properties` shows the following properties:

```
awt.toolkit = sun.awt.X11.XToolkit
file.encoding = UTF-8
file.separator = /
java.awt.graphicsenv = sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment
java.awt.printerjob = sun.print.PSPrinterJob
java.class.path = /mnt/c/Workspace/library/java/
    .
    /home/fred/.local/share/py4j/py4j0.10.7.jar
java.class.version = 55.0
java.home = /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64
java.io.tmpdir = /tmp
java.library.path = /mnt/c/Workspace/build/library/
```

### Attempts to solve the problem

#### Making sure I have a valid native library

Doing an `ls` on the java.library.path `/mnt/c/Workspace/build/library/` shows the library `libMngr.so`.

If I delete `libMngr.so` from that location and then try to run Java complains it can't find the library.

Doing the `nm` command on `libMngr.so` shows the following:

```
000000000021f269 T Java_com_mgr_1api_1JNI_createInstance
```

So Java can find the native library and it has the symbol of the function.

Doing the `objdump` command:

```
$objdump -f build/library/libMngr.so

build/library/libMngr.so:     file format elf64-x86-64
architecture: i386:x86-64, flags 0x00000150:
HAS_SYMS, DYNAMIC, D_PAGED
start address 0x000000000018aee0
```

Shows that the native library is 64 bit and according to the `-XshowSettings:properties` I am using 64 bit Java.

I have even put a print statement right before `System.loadLibrary("Mngr");` in `mgr_api_JNI.java` to make sure that the native library is loaded only once.

#### Update

I have regenerated the header file from `mgr_api_JNI.java` and copied the function declaration to the `.cpp` file to make sure the function name is correct. But I still get the same error.

#### Making sure I have valid Java classes

If I do an `ls` on the java.class.path `/mnt/c/Workspace/library/java/` I find all of the Java classes from compiling `mgr_api_JNI.java`.

If I delete the classes and try to run Java, then Java complains it can't find the classes.

Doing a `grep -r createInstance` on the java.class.path `/mnt/c/Workspace/library/java/` returns:

```
Binary file com/mgr_api_JNI.class matches
com/mgr_api_JNI.java: public native void createInstance(com.mgr_api_types.EDisplayType displayType,
```

So Java can find the the compiled Java class and it has the `createInstance` method in it.

### Questions

It appears to me that Java can find all of the needed classes and the native library, but I am still getting the `UnsatisfiedLinkError` error.

Why am I still getting this error?

What do I need to do to help Java find/recognize the `createInstance` method?

Comment: @Elliot Frisch I don't think that is correct. Everything I have read has indicated that `java.library.path` is just like `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` in Linux. It just provides a list of directories for Java to search to find libraries. Also, if I had to specify the library then Java would have returned an error telling me it couldn't find the library.

Comment: You're also loading `Mngr` but have a library file named `libMgr.so`, not sure if it's just a typo in the question...

Comment: Yeah, that was a typo on my part. It is really `libMngr.so`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is your error**

You have library file: `/mnt/c/Workspace/build/library/libMgr.so` but you load this one in your code: `System.loadLibrary("Mngr");` - you have a typo

**You can make sure that in case of correct name it works as expected**

When you "leave" initial `JVM`, `-Djava.library.path` is no longer a valid place to provide info to other JVM. I don't know the details of `py4j.GatewayConnection`, but it's good to make sure you don't run another `JVM` instance or, that you don't use `JNI` there.

I suggest following tests:

- set the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to location where your lib is
- make sure you can access library in the code with only `public class mgr_api_JNI` (without Python bridge engine)
- if there is a chance that you second JVM is loading native code (and can't find it), try to use `_JAVA_OPTIONS=-Djava.library.path=[path to library]`. This way, all the `JVMs` will "see" the location - but you should do that just for testing purposes

It definitely looks like issue with loading the lib from another process. If I reduce your code to something like this:

```
.
|-- Makefile
|-- README.md
|-- c
|   `-- com_mgr_api_JNI.cc
|-- java
|   `-- com
|       |-- mgr_api_JNI.java
|       `-- mgr_api_types
|           |-- ECommType.java
|           `-- EDisplayType.java
|-- lib
`-- target
```

and the code itself

**com_mgr_api_JNI.cc**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "jni.h"
#include "com_mgr_api_JNI.h"

using namespace std;

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_mgr_1api_1JNI_createInstance
  (JNIEnv *env, jobject cls, jobject a, jstring b, jobject c, jstring d) {
  cout << "Hello";
}
```

**java/com/mgr_api_JNI.java**

```
package com;
import com.mgr_api_types.*;

public class mgr_api_JNI
{
  static {
    try {
      System.loadLibrary("Mngr"); // Use "-Djava.library.path=[path to library]" option to load this library
    } catch (UnsatisfiedLinkError e) {
      System.err.println("Native code library 'Mngr' failed to load.\n" + e);
    }
  }

  public native void createInstance(  com.mgr_api_types.EDisplayType displayType,
                                      String displaySerialNumber,
                                      com.mgr_api_types.ECommType commType,
                                      String portName);

  public static void main(String [] arg) {

    mgr_api_JNI obj = new mgr_api_JNI();
    obj.createInstance(new com.mgr_api_types.EDisplayType(), "", new com.mgr_api_types.ECommType(), "");

  }
}
```

**java/com/mgr_api_types/ECommType.java**

```
package com.mgr_api_types;

public class ECommType { }
```

**cat java/com/mgr_api_types/EDisplayType.java**

```
package com.mgr_api_types;

public class EDisplayType { }
```

and I build the code

**Makefile.common**

```
ARCH=$(shell uname -s | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]')
ifeq ($(ARCH),darwin)
  EXT=dylib
else
  EXT=so
endif
```

**Makefile**

```
include Makefile.common

all: compilejava compilec

compilec:
    c++ -std=c++11 -g -shared -fpic -I${JAVA_HOME}/include -I${JAVA_HOME}/include/$(ARCH) c/com_mgr_api_JNI.cc -o lib/libMngr.$(EXT)

compilejava:
    $(JAVA_HOME)/bin/javac -h c -d target -cp target java/com/mgr_api_types/EDisplayType.java
    $(JAVA_HOME)/bin/javac -h c -d target -cp target java/com/mgr_api_types/ECommType.java
    $(JAVA_HOME)/bin/javac -h c -d target -cp target java/com/mgr_api_JNI.java

test:
    $(JAVA_HOME)/bin/java -Djava.library.path=$(LD_LIBRARY_PATH):./lib -cp target com.mgr_api_JNI

clean:
    -rm -rfv target/*
    -rm c/*.h
    -rm -rf lib/*
```

it works as expected

```
make test
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-12.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -Djava.library.path=:./lib -cp target com.mgr_api_JNI
Hello
```

I think you have a situation where you class is called from either another instance of JVM, or from something called via JNI, or from another process and your `-Djava.library.path` is gone.

Also, try to use `System.load("full/path/of/library.so")` to make sure you can access the library from `JVM`.

Comment: `libMgr.so` was a typo, it is really `libMngr.so`. But I will look into your suggestions.

Comment: It turned out to be an issue where I had another instance of a JVM still running that hadn't died. Once I killed it the error went away.

Comment: @Fred - good to know this can lead to errors in this particular case. I am pretty sure I will investigate py4j to some extent :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem occurs when the runtime can not load the corresponding native function in a shared library.

So, in these cases it's always good to regenerate the header file to see if the function name is correct.

In this case your function name looks suspicious

```
Java_com_1mgr_1api_1JNI_createInstance
```

The generated name uses the `_1` to encode a literal underscore in the Java class/function name. So, based on the class name `mgr_api_JNI` the name should be

```
Java_com_mgr_1api_1JNI_createInstance
```

instead. i.e. the first `_1` is just a plain underscore `_`, and this is also what I see when generating a header file for a class with that name.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't see `Java_com_mgr_1api_1JNI_createInstance` (missing the `_1`) anywhere in my post or code.

Comment: Yes, I have regenerated the header file and then copied the function declaration into the `.cpp` file.

Comment: @Fred Yes, it's not in your post, and that's the problem. i.e. the extra `_1` between the package name and function name is _incorrect_, and should just be an underscore `_`.

Comment: Understood. I will look into it.